# How to tell JetBrains IDE that template string is JS code

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, jetbrains-ide

I have an ES6 template string, which represents JS code. If I put `<script>` tags around it, JetBrains IntelliJ will do syntax highlighting and checking, but not if there are no script tags.

Is there a way to tell JetBrains IDE how to interpret the template string?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It's definitely the presence/absence of the html tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDEA auto-injects HTML in JavaScript string literals/template string if there are HTML tags in it; to inject other languages, you need adding language injection manually - for example, the language can be temporary injected via **Inject language or reference** intention available on `Alt+Enter`:

[image]

You can also annotate your injection with comments to make it permanent:

```
//language=JS
const baz = `console.log("test")`
```

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html for more information